# C++ COM add-in - find if MS Word, PPT, Excel has unsaved changes

Tags: c++, excel, ms-word, powerpoint, comaddin

I have created a basic COM add-in for MS office apps like Word, PPT, Excel in Visual C++ using _IDTExtensibility2 interface.

Now i want my add-in to find if Word, PPT, Excel has any unsaved changes.

FYI: I have not chosen VSTO or Office JS add-in due to dependency/deployment reasons.

Kindly provide solution in C++.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

An Office host `Application` instance is passed to the `OnConnection` method implemented in your code. Depending on the host you could use the [Saved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.saved) property, for example, in case of Word the `Document` class provides the `Saved` property which returns `true` if the specified document or template has not changed since it was last saved. `False` if Microsoft Word displays a prompt to save changes when the document is closed.

In case of Excel you can use the [Workbook.Saved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saved) property which returns `true` if no changes have been made to the specified workbook since it was last saved.

In case of PowerPoint the [Presentation.Saved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.saved) property determines whether changes have been made to a presentation since it was last saved.

Comment: // _IDTExtensibility2 Methods
public:
         CComQIPtr<Word::_Application> pWordApp;
         CComQIPtr<Word::_Document> pWordDoc;

         STDMETHOD(OnConnection)(LPDISPATCH Application, ext_ConnectMode ConnectMode, LPDISPATCH AddInInst, SAFEARRAY * * custom)
         {
             pWordApp = Application;
             pWordApp->get_ActiveDocument(&pWordDoc);
             if (pWordDoc)  {  MessageBoxW(NULL, L"ActiveDoc present", L"My Addin", MB_OK); }
             else   {  MessageBoxW(NULL, L"ActiveDoc not present", L"My Addin", MB_OK);   }
          return S_OK;
         }

Comment: I tried using Saved property for Word, but when i open word i didn't get the active document object i.e., i get "ActiveDocument not present" message box.

Maybe it is too early to call get_activedocument() as during onConnection the document is yet to be created. But i don't know how/where to call it once document is created.

I tried calling it inside onStartupComplete() too, still object is NULL. I also tried calling it inside thread after sleeping for few seconds so that i create document in that sleep time, still object is NULL.

Kindly guide along with some sample C++ code/projects.